# scm-manager Windows service on server 2012

Tags: scmmanager

Tried many option but service starts but webserver not responding, if I launch manually it works.

Moved .scm dir into localsystem home, nothing changed, any idea? Thanks

Comment: Which version of SCM-Manager do you use? Do you see any problems in the log?

Comment: Can you try again with the latest 2.0.0 release of SCM-Manager? The instructions for windows can be found here: https://scm-manager.org/docs/2.0.x/en/installation/windows/

Comment: thanks for the help, but chosen not to use it...